# Using group by to get category counts, but one category is missing in output table as data is not available

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

Hive script issue: I have an issue with getting counts over groupby using Hive, when the count is zero. If a category is available in input table, I was able to see the counts in output table. But when a particular category is not available in input table, it doesnt appear as zero in output table. Instead that category is vanished from output table. Any help here is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**Input and Output Tables:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mfrh6.png)

Input table is partitioned on "**Year**" column.

**Hive Code I tried:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zbo2F.png)

Comment: do you have another table with all the bins?

Comment: I earlier simplified the question to make it less confusing. I shouldn't have done that. Sorry. Updated the question with 100% actual scenario. Could you please check again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you overcomplicated the logic. To get the results that you are expected, you can `UNION ALL` three simple queries as follows:

```
SELECT 'ada' attribute, 96 bin, COUNT(*) FROM input_table WHERE bin = 96
UNION ALL SELECT 'ada' attribute, 97 bin, COUNT(*) FROM input_table WHERE bin = 97
UNION ALL SELECT 'ada' attribute, 98 bin, COUNT(*) FROM input_table WHERE bin = 98
```

These type of queries with implicit `GROUP BY` will always return something, even if there is no record that matches the `WHERE` condition.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ec38014552ceaa9fa65f9e77310ac8c8)**:

```
attribute | bin | (No column name)
:-------- | --: | ---------------:
ada       |  96 |                3
ada       |  97 |                0
ada       |  98 |                5
```

Comment: I earlier simplified the question to make it less confusing. I shouldn't have done that. Sorry. Updated the question with 100% actual scenario. Could you please check again.

Comment: @kumar: it is not a good practice to substantially change the question after answers were posted. I can only suggest that you accept one of the answer that responded to your *original* question and ask a new one.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `select from values` syntax

```
SELECT
  input_table.attribute,
  bins.bin,
  COUNT(input_table.bin) bin_count 
FROM
  (VALUES (96),
          (97),
          (98))bins (bin)
left JOIN input_table
        ON bins.bin = input_table.bin 
group by bins.bin,input_table.attribute
```

Comment: I earlier simplified the question to make it less confusing. I shouldn't have done that. Sorry. Updated the question with 100% actual scenario. Could you please check again.